# My GWT app isn't running a native function off of a JSNI call. Any takers?

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I'm attempting to run a native Java function off of a JSNI call in my GWT app.  It looks something like this:

package foo.client;

public class AAA implements EntryPoint, UIupdate {

```
public native void initChangeFunc() /*-{
    $wnd.jsChangeView = function () {

        this.@foo.client.AAA::changeToHistory();
        alert("got here");
    };
}-*/;
public void changeToHistory() {
    Window.alert("Hello World");
    //Change view here.
    this.changeView("history");
    this.changeHistoryView("bydate");
};
```

...

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
```

...

```
    this.initChangeFunc();
}
```

}

Attaching the jsChangeView() function call to a link onclick() in the front-end and clicking it results in a "got here" alert, but not a "Hello World" alert, and the other two functions aren't running either.  GWT isn't my area of expertise, and this isn't my app, so I know I'm missing something basic here.  Any takers?

Comment: You'll want to wrap your `function` with `$entry()`, i.e., `jsChangeView = $entry(function() {...});` as well.

Answer (score 3):

`this.@foo.client.AAA::changeToHistory()` is only referencing the method (a "function pointer" if you like, or, in JavaScript, just a "function"), it doesn't call it. You have to write `this.@foo.client.AAA::changeToHistory()()` to actually make the call.

It's more obvious when the method has arguments, e.g.: `this.@foo.client.AAA::changeToHistory(Ljava/lang/String;I)` vs. `this.@foo.client.AAA::changeToHistory(Ljava/lang/String;I)("foo", 3)`.

Comment: Sort of working, except my Firefox error console is now complaining that "this.changeToHistory is not a function".  I'm assuming it's attempting to reference that as a local javascript function.  I suppose I could also declare that as a native function, but then I'd be back to square one when I attempted to call the internal functions.

Comment: Oh, didn't see: `this` is a keyword in Javascript, not a variable; your "this" will depend on the context the function is called in; most probably the `$wnd`. A common pattern is to assign `this` to a variable, and reference that variable from the anonymous function: `var that=this; $wnd.jsChangeView=$entry(function(){that....;});` (also added `$entry` as suggested by Jason Hall, which will among other things run your `GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler` in case of error in `changeToHistory`)

Comment: Found the $entry solution.  Other problems abound, but that's all on the Java end of things.  Thank you very much, you've been a lifesaver.